# SQL Script that will keep Null values

Tags: sql

I have a SQL script that returns data in column 4. The data being returned is Null values and the SQL code for the front end account. I need to covert the values so that the front end account show but also keep all the nulls. When I run my SQL script and replace the front end values I lose the nulls and the total overall results are less.

Sample Script frontend values converted:

```
Select c.Customer
, c.name
, l.City
, a.account
, case '#sortby#'
    when 'Customer' then c.customer
    else c.name end
from customer c, location l, Account a
where c.hmycustomer = l.hmy
and c.code = a.hmy
```

however if I run the script like this I get all results including Nulls but the values are the hmy instead of the front end code.

```
Select c.Customer
, c.name
, l.City
, c.code
, case '#sortby#'
    when 'Customer' then c.customer
    else c.name end
from customer c, location l
where c.hmycustomer = l.hmy
enter code here

Customer |Name |City |Code 
---------|-----|-----|-----
   1     |John |Santa|Null
   2     |Mary |Santa|268
   3     |Josh |Santa|273
   4     |Bert |Santa|Null

code 268 should =1234
code 273 should =4563
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Left join will return all records from customer table please check it :

```
SELECT
    c.Customer, c.name, l.City, a.account, c.code, a.hmy,
    CASE '#sortby#'
        WHEN 'Customer' THEN c.customer
        ELSE c.name 
    END
FROM
    ((customer c
LEFT JOIN 
    location l ON c.hmycustomer = l.hmy)
LEFT JOIN 
    Account a ON c.code = a.hmy);
```

Comment: This works in SQL, but does not work when you to run the report through the database. I will need to tweak a bit more, but this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Please check there may be some coding issues, sql query which is working in console will work fine in report.  if working fine, mark answer.